# Ability to use Mirth Connect GUI to do more complex mappings vs. javascript

Tags: xml, mirth

I am evaluating EAI/middleware products.  I wanted to know if the below example could be done within the GUI alone vs. having to write javascript.  One of the business requirements placed on my selection is that non-developers can build complex mappings.

I am trying to accomplish this in Mirth right now but it doesn't seem like I can do this.

Related to this, if someone has knowledge of another product that does what I want below with pure GUI please point me in that direction.  Or if there is some module/plug-in to purchase for Mirth that extends the mapping ability to be pure GUI based.

I realize I may be living in a fantasy world that a pure GUI solution exists but such is my lot in life. :)

Assume there are 3 XML data elements in the source XML called:

Alpha
Delta
Omega
And in the destination XML there is a data element called Result.

The value in Result will be 15 if:

Alpha >10 but less than <50
Delta is "hello"
Omega is not 11

Another rule may be the value in Result will be 20 if:

Alpha, Delta and Omega are all 20

Thanks,
Dano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, conditional logic like that must be done in JS connectors. Sorry!